# How to tag images in meteor

Tags: image, meteor

I have uploaded images in database and want to tag the same images using meteor.Also the user should be able to edit these tags as well .

I saw [autoform](http://autoform.meteor.com/update-each) for tagging but cant connect with images.

Comment: wich package are using to upload images?

Comment: using fs: collection

Comment: you can add any text you want to the file using `fsFile.metadata`

Comment: can I use this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/blueimp-load-image

Comment: @Ethaan: any example/link to share its usage?

Comment: let me work on a demo tomorrow and i will send it to you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick recipe:

### Packages

Install the following packages:

- [aldeed:simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema)
- [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2)
- [aldeed:autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform)
- [yogiben:autoform-file](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-autoform-file)

### Schema

Add the following `image` field to your collection schema:

```js
"image": {
  type: Object
},
"image.$.file": {
  type: String,
  autoform: {
    afFieldInput: {
      type: 'fileUpload',
      collection: 'Images',
      label: 'Choose file' // optional
    }
  }
},
"image.$.tags": {
  type: Array // enables multiple tagging
},
"images.$.tags.$": {
  type: String // tags are strings
}
```

### Template

Create an auto-form in any template:

```
{{> quickForm collection="CollectionName" type="insert"}}
```